# A non-diskette MS-DOS boot disk

Tags: boot, format, ms-dos, floppy

I want to format a device to be an MS-DOS boot disk but I dont have a floppy disk drive. Unless you show me one on ebay thats 5 dollars or less I cant buy it. I wanted to know If I could format another device, I have plenty of them for example SD, micro SD, flash drive some I don't even know the name of but If you know the name I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could very easily create a bootable USB with dos with the old [HP drive formatting too](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm)l/.

Depending on your needs, you might also be able to use [freedos](http://www.freedos.org/) from a cd, or possibly install it to other devices from that.

Comment: This is great but can you direct me to the HP website where I can download it (i would really appreciate it :)

Comment: HP replaced it with a new version thats inferior - third party sites are the only way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download the HP Flash Utility and the Windows 98 MS-DOS System Files.

Follow instructions listed on this site:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/46707-ms-dos-bootable-flash-drive-create.html

And next give a bit more info on which OS you are using, etc.  I am going under assumption that you are using Windows.

Comment: Yeh Im having some problem with the software can you direct me to someone who can help me

Comment: hpflash1.zip
(http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/42022d1260810265-ms-dos-bootable-flash-drive-create-hpflash1.zip)

&

win98boot.zip
(http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/42023d1260810265-ms-dos-bootable-flash-drive-create-win98boot.zip)